# Is there a way to filter a counter column in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have been unable to decipher on how to proceed with a use case....

I want to keep count of some items, and query the data such that

```
counter_value < threshold value
```

Now in cassandra, indexes cannot be made on counters, that is something that is a problem, is there a workaround modelling which can be done to accomplish something similar??

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have partially answered your own question, saying what you want to query. So lets say first model the data the way you will query it later.

If you want to query through counter value, it cannot be a counter type. As it doesn't complies the two conditions needed to query the data

1. Cannot be part of index
2. Cannot be part of the partition key

Counters are the most efficient way to do fast writes in Cassandra for a counter use of case. But unfortunately they cannot be part of where clause, because of above two restrictions.

So if you want to solve the problem using Cassandra, change the type to a long in Cassandra, make it the **clustering key** or make an **index** over that column. In any case this will slower your writes and increase the latency of every operation of updating counter value, as you will be using the anti parttern of read-before-write.

I would recommend to use the **index**.

Last but not least, I would consider using a SQL database for this problem.

Comment: I cannot use mysql, I have a huge dataset, and lots of writes which won't work with sql database for me and read before write is something I really don't want to do, I will have to use higher consistency level which will kill the performance, Is there any other way I can approach this?

Comment: you want to do these queries in real time?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're trying to return as a result, you might be able to do something with a user defined aggregate function.  You can put arbitrary code in the user defined function to filter based on the value of the counter.

See some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828952/how-to-get-top-5-records-in-cassandra-2-2/31837422#31837422) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32510572/aggregate-sum-on-counter-type-of-cassandra/32524877#32524877).

Other approaches would be to filter the returned rows on the client side, or to load the data into Spark and filter the rows in Spark.

Comment: I was also thinking that finding a good way to aggregate the counter data would be the way to go on this one.

Comment: @Aaron yes, that is perfect, the only problem right now is, I have to wait for a stable release of 2.2 to use that, aggregates are not available in 2.1.9.